# Rotating a 2D PGM Image Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, rotation, pgm

I am working on a homework project to rotate a simple 2D array holding RGB values for a PGM file.

I've read many posts in these forums about how to do this in C, and I've almost got it working. My output file has the correct dimensions and is rotated, but there is a thick black border around the top and sides. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I modified the code presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6085428/2557682) to get started, and this is the `rotate90` function I'm working on now:

```
PGMImage* rotate90(PGMImage *old_img)
{
    int x, y;
    PGMImage *new_img = malloc(sizeof(PGMImage));
    new_img->maxVal = old_img->maxVal;
    new_img->width = old_img->height;
    new_img->height = old_img->width;
    for (x = 0; x < old_img->width; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < old_img->height; y++)
        {
            new_img->data[old_img->height - 1 - y][x].r = old_img->data[x][y].r;
            new_img->data[old_img->height - 1 - y][x].g = old_img->data[x][y].g;
            new_img->data[old_img->height - 1 - y][x].b = old_img->data[x][y].b;
        }
    }
    return new_img;
}

void main()
{
    PGMImage* img = malloc(sizeof(PGMImage));
    getPGMfile("columns.pgm", img);
    save("columns_new.ppm", rotate90(img));
}
```

The `save()` and `getPGMfile()` functions work perfectly on their own.
It's only when I pass the result of my `rotate90()` function to `save()` that I get the funky results.

Comment: Are you allocating space for the `.data` member array?

Comment: Thanks for the question luser droog. The `data` array is allocated at 800 x 800 within the `PGMImage` typedef (in the header file). I'm only working with images of max size 640 x 480.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying `memcpy(new_img, old_img, sizeof(PGMImage)` after the `malloc` statement. Maybe some other attributes besides width and height are not initialized. And also, if the `data` variable is a pointer, did you malloc a piece of memory for `data` for the new_img object?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion WDan. I added the `memcopy` code you suggested but it didn't change anything - the only attributes `PGMImage` has are `maxVal`, `width`, `height`, and `data` (which is a 2D array of structs holding the `r` `g` and `b` ints).